Does the Heaviside function belong to $W^{s,p}$ for some $s>0$?
Let us consider $n$-fold tensor product of Heaviside functions:
\begin{equation}
H(x_1, \cdots, x_n) := \prod_{i=1}^n \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x_i)
\end{equation}
Then, for any bounded open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ including the origin, I wonder if this $H$ belongs to the Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ for some $s \in (0,\infty)$ and $p \in [1,\infty]$.
For non-integer $s>0$, I am aware that there are two definitions: Bessel potential vs Sobolev–Slobodeckij, so I would like to ask for both cases.
I am pretty sure that $H$ cannot belong to $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ for $s \geq 1$, but I am curious about general cases.

For $s \in \mathbb{N}$: The only candidate for the gradient is the zero vector. Assume $H$ is weakly differentiable. In that case, for any $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n$: $0 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi \partial_i H = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} H \partial_i \varphi = -\int_{[0,\infty)^n}  \partial_i \varphi $. Think about whether the last integral is necessarily $0$.

Also, on a trivial note: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert H \rvert^p = \infty$ for any $p \in [1, \infty)$. So already, $p = \infty$.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend  Oops...I forgot about resticting to a bounded domain. It has been fixed.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Also, I do not understand what you mean by "the only candidate for gradient is the zero vector". $H$ has the delta distribution as its weak derivative, which is not a function. That is why I am confident that $H$ is not in $W^{s,p}$ for any $s \geq 1$.

I argued that if $H$ had a derivative in $L^p$, it would have to be zero.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Oh, I see. So, that seems to confirm that $H \notin W^{s,p}$ for any $s \in \mathbb{N}$. How about the case $s \in (0,1)$? Do you have any idea in this case?

It does confirm that. I have no idea for $s \in (0, 1)$ yet. I might have to compute that
